# What does number_of_cliques and max_clique calculate?

Tags: networkx

I am not sure what `max_clique` does and what `number_of_cliques` does

```
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import clique
clique.max_clique(G)
```

and

```
clique.number_of_cliques(G)
```

Not clear from the [doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/clique.html)

Comment: Your link to the docs is to v1.9.  Networkx is now on v2.2.  I believe these functions remain the same, but they are now in different places.  What version of networkx are you using (`nx.__version__`)?

Comment: @Joel I am sorry I am using v2.2

Comment: Just be aware that `number_of_cliques` is no longer contained within `approximation`.  It is now in `networkx.algorithms.clique`.  The `max_clique` algorithm is an approximate algorithm, so it still sits within `approximation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_clique` finds what is hopefully the largest (or a largest) clique in the graph.  It will return a set of nodes which form a clique, with a reasonable likelihood that there is no larger clique in the network.  It is approximate because the calculation itself is expensive (NP-complete).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

`number_of_cliques` (at least in networkx v2.2) returns a dict whose keys are the nodes of the graphs and whose values are the number of maximal cliques that the given node is in.  A maximal clique means that if 0-1, 0-2, 1-2 and 0-3 are edges, then the maximal cliques of node 0 are {0,1,2} and {0,3}.  The clique {0,1} does not count because it is contained in  a larger clique. Nodes 1 and 2 each have a single maximal clique {0,1,2} and node 3 has a single maximal clique {0,3}.  So `number_of_cliques` returns the dict `{0:2, 1:1, 2:1, 3:1}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample:

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.Graph()
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 0),(1, 4),(4, 2)]
G1.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw_networkx(G1)
```

[image]

```
res = nx.find_cliques(G1)
cliques = [item for item in res]
cliques = sorted(cliques, key=lambda item: -len(item))
for item in cliques:
    print(item)
```

[image]

```
max_clique(G1)
```

[image]